# Install MySQL 5.6 from source code on CentOS 7.0, but nothing happened

Tags: mysql, centos, percona, centos7, mysql-5.6

Here's my code:

```
cd ~ && mkdir src && cd src

groupadd mysql
useradd -g mysql -s /sbin/nologin mysql
wget http://www.percona.com/downloads/Percona-Server-5.6/Percona-Server-5.6.22-71.0/source/tarball/percona-server-5.6.22-71.0.tar.gz
tar zxf percona-server-5.6.22-71.0.tar.gz
cd percona-server-5.6.22-71.0
sh BUILD/autorun.sh
cmake \
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/percona-server-5.6.22-71.0 \
-DSYSCONFDIR=/opt/percona-server-5.6.22-71.0 \
-DOPTIMIZER_TRACE=OFF \
-DWITH_DEBUG=OFF \
-DWITH_EXTRA_CHARSETS=none \
-DWITH_UNIT_TESTS=OFF \
-DWITH_ZLIB=bundled \
-DWITH_ARCHIVE_STORAGE_ENGINE=OFF \
-DWITH_BLACKHOLE_STORAGE_ENGINE=OFF \
-DWITH_CSV_STORAGE_ENGINE=OFF \
-DWITH_FEDERATED_STORAGE_ENGINE=OFF \
-DWITH_INNOBASE_STORAGE_ENGINE=ON \
-DWITH_MYISAM_STORAGE_ENGINE=ON \
-DWITH_PARTITION_STORAGE_ENGINE=ON \
-DWITH_HEAP_STORAGE_ENGINE=OFF && make -j `cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l` && make install && make clean && cd ..

ln -s /opt/percona-server-5.6.22-71.0/ /opt/mysql  
sed -i 's/executing mysqld_safe/executing mysqld_safe\n\n# gperftools\nexport LD_PRELOAD=\/usr\/lib64\/libtcmalloc.so\n/g' /opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe

mkdir -p /data/mysql/bin
mkdir -p /data/mysql/data
mkdir -p /data/mysql/group
mkdir -p /data/mysql/log
mkdir -p /data/mysql/slow
chown -R mysql:mysql /data/mysql
nano /opt/mysql/my.cnf
```

After I config my.cnf file, then

```
chmod 755 /opt/mysql/scripts/mysql_install_db
/opt/mysql/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/opt/mysql --datadir=/data/mysql/data
```

It says

```
[root@var4 src]# /opt/percona-server-5.6.21-70.1/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedi/ --datadir=/data/mysql/data/70.1/
Installing MySQL system tables...[root@var4 src]#
```

I tried percona-server-5.6.21-70.1 & percona-server-5.6.22-71.0, both failed.

Then I clean up the my.cnf content, failed again.

Maybe I will reinstall the CentOS 6.5. But does anyone has met this issue before?

Comment: Centos 6.5 failed again.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason for install it manually?
You can install Percona 5.6 using percona yum repository easily:

yum install http://www.percona.com/downloads/percona-release/redhat/0.1-3/percona-release-0.1-3.noarch.rpm

Then:

yum  install  Percona-Server-server-56  Percona-Server-client-56